# Animation on image resource change

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-imageview, transition

I am trying to change repeatedly images in image view (it doesn't matter what component to use). I need to change background image each N seconds.
I have tried to use Animation drawable declaring images in xml file.
It works, but I don't know to apply any effect to it, like fade in,blur or something other.
So my task is to change periodically background image with transition effect.
Please suggest how to deal with this problem, I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I used an image switcher to switch images in regular intervals

xml part

```
 <ImageSwitcher
                         android:id="@+id/smsimg"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                         android:src="@drawable/defaultimage" />
```

class code was like this

```
 private final int[] images  = {  R.drawable.vava, R.drawable.vavaone,R.drawable.vavatwo,R.drawable.vavathree,R.drawable.vavafour,
                };


 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    img=(ImageSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.smsimg);
            startAnimatedBackground();  



     private void startAnimatedBackground() {
                Animation aniIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        android.R.anim.fade_in);
                aniIn.setDuration(3000);
                Animation aniOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                aniOut.setDuration(3000);

                final ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.smsimg);
                imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(aniIn);
                imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(aniOut);
                imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(images[index]);

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (isRunning) {
                            index++;
                            index = index % images.length;
                            Log.d("Intro Screen", "Change Image " + index);
                            imageSwitcher.setImageResource(images[index]);
                            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
                        }
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);

            }
```